# How can I draw such the below plot in R? A heatmap with a barplot on the top

Tags: r, heatmap

How can I draw such the below plot in R? Not a table just a heatmap with a barplot on the top.

[image]

Here is the table:

```
  Gene name log2FC  Alteration frequency
Gene1   0.230749533 2.91
Gene2   0.070357349 1.64
Gene3   -0.239713974    1.91
Gene4   0.703365372 0.82
Gene5   0.327406476 2.37
Gene6   0.788362186 2.18
Gene7   -0.145366946    1.73
Gene8   0.193414478 16.11
Gene9   -0.427479686    1.55
Gene10  -0.548639578    1.18
Gene11  -0.227693913    5.46
Gene12  0.007319619 0.82
Gene13  -0.282273491    1.55
Gene14  -0.127434584    9.55
Gene15  -0.465189842    0.82
Gene16  0.075561033 0.82
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I recommend the gt package, here a reference: https://rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to draw the plot and not a table. I just couldn't find an example and draw something similar to the thing in my mind in excel.

Comment: gt provides a lot of visual resources, such as coloring by a variable and combining with plots